# Spring XML Aspect before Annotation an Class not working

Tags: java, spring, aop, sap-commerce-cloud

i'm currently trying to using a custom annotation at method and class level to execute code via an aspect. It is a SAP Commerce Cloud project (newest version).

**On method level it works fine** but if the annotation is **on the class it doesn't** enter my Aspect. Why? Hope someone can help me.

**Annotation**

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserGroupAuthorize {

    UserGroup[] groups() default {};

}
```

**spring.xml**

```
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" expose-proxy="true"/>

    <bean id="userGroupAuthorizeAspect" class="com.[...].annotation.UserGroupAuthorizeAspect">
        <constructor-arg name="userService" ref="userService"/>
    </bean>
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:aspect id="userGroupAuthorizeAspectId" ref="userGroupAuthorizeAspect">
            <aop:pointcut id="userGroupAuthorizeAnnotation" expression="@annotation(userGroupAuthorize)"/>
            <aop:before pointcut-ref="userGroupAuthorizeAnnotation" method="authorize"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

**Aspect**

```
public class UserGroupAuthorizeAspect {

    public void authorize(UserGroupAuthorize userGroupAuthorize) {
       ...
    }
...
}
```

**Usages**

@UserGroupAuthorize(groups = {UserGroup.CUSTOMER, UserGroup.CUSTOMER_MANAGERGROUP})

like said on method(works) or on class(works not)

Answer (score 1):

finally I found a solution on Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj-advise-methods

my solution looks like this:

```
    <aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:aspect ref="userGroupAuthorizeAspect">
            <aop:before pointcut="@annotation(userGroupAuthorize)" 
                        method="authorizeMethod"/>
        </aop:aspect>
        <aop:aspect ref="userGroupAuthorizeAspect">
            <aop:around pointcut="@within(com.[...].annotation.UserGroupAuthorize) and execution(* *(..))" 
                        method="authorizeClass"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

```
    public Object authorizeClass(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
        UserGroupAuthorize userGroupAuthorize = signature.getMethod().getDeclaringClass()
            .getAnnotation(UserGroupAuthorize.class);
        authorizeMethod(userGroupAuthorize);
        return pjp.proceed();
    }
```

Comment: You would not have needed Baeldung, if you had studied the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) for a little while. Besides, the Baeldung article does not explain your problem at all, nor does your answer. Simply showing a solution without any explanation is not helpful for other readers. The root cause of your problem is, that `@annotation()` only matches annotated methods, while `@within()` matches annotated types. This is why you need both.